# Printers already installed but would like to block spooler to prevent future print jobs

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, printing

I have tens of client machines over domain with Windows 7/8/8.1 installed and almost all machines are connected to different printers. Only one main printer is listed in AD which can be easily disabled, but the issue is many of them are connected to a shared or another network printer and sometimes directly (USB).

How can I handle Group Policy so that I can prevent the spooler service from executing any future print orders? As the spooler is the service responsible for printing whatever the printer was local, network or shared.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me get this straight, you want to prevent anyone from printing anything to any printer?

If so, then use GPO to disable the Print Spooler service in your Default Domain Policy. As long as you don't have any GPO's with inheritance blocking enabled linked to any OU's that have computer objects in them then this will effectively disable the Print Spooler service on all of your domain members.

Comment: Correct. Would you guide how to disable print spooler using GPO?

Comment: No. We don't provide tutorials here. If you want to work in the IT field in a professional capacity then that means having to do some work for yourself. I've given you a push down the road already. Here's another push - https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=how+to+disable+a+service+with+group+policy